# Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title'

Tags: android, coding-style

I am implementing ActionBar to set the color for text using this style script in xml but getting error when I run my application time does anybody have idea what I have missing

this is my style.xml file

```
<!-- Start with the Holographic Light theme -->
<style name="Theme.IOSched" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/window_background</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>

    <!-- custom attributes 
    <item name="textHeaderMaxLines">@integer/text_header_max_lines</item>
    <item name="trackAbstractMaxLines">@integer/track_abstract_max_lines</item>-->
</style>

<style name="Theme.IOSched.Home" parent="style/Theme.IOSched">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/window_background_home</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/actionbar_background</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/accent_1</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBarText</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title"> <!-- getting here error-->
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/accent_1</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>

error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
```

Comment: Did you set your Build Target to 3.0 in Project Properties?

Comment: I am having this error when playServices is not included and android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" is giving error

Comment: See my answer on question [appcompat_v7: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23231174/appcompat-v7-error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-t/33052594#33052594)

Comment: See my answer on question [appcompat_v7: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23231174/appcompat-v7-error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-t/33052594#33052594)

Comment: See my answer on question [appcompat_v7: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23231174/appcompat-v7-error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-t/33052594#33052594)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

`TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title` appears to have been added in API Level 13. Make sure your build target is set to 13, not just 11.

Comment: Silly to have to mention this, but I forgot the step so perhaps it will help someone else, too: don't forget to "Clean" the project after changing your project's target version!

Answer (score 16):

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion=...
    android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
```

and

**Project Properties** -> **Project Build Target** = 11 or above

These 2 things fixed the problem for me!

Answer (score 8):

I tried to change target sdk to 13 but does not works!!
then when I changed `compileSdkVersion 13` to `compileSdkVersion 14` is compiled successfully :)

> NOTE: I Work with Android Studio not Eclipse

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you've set your target API (different from the target SDK) in the Project Properties (not the manifest) to be at least 4.0/API 14.

Comment: This one is perfect. Upvoted. It would be great if you explain some more which can help us to understand better.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because in r6 it shows an error when you try to extend private styles.

Refer to this [link](http://code.google.com/p/styled-action-bar/issues/detail?id=2)

Answer (score 0):

```
<style name="Theme.IOSched" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/window_background</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
</style>
```

you can not give your own color and backgroud in item windowBackground.
give your color in your /color.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but if anyone comes up with this problem, i post what solved my problem:

I was trying to add the **Action Bar Sherlock** to my proyect when i get the error:

```
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar'.
```

I turns out that the action bar sherlock proyect and my proyect had differents *minSdkVersion* and *targetSdkVersion*. Changing that parameters to match in both proyect solved my problem.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
```