# Errors in resource files when using ActionBarSherlock 4.1.0

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock

I successfully compiled ActionBarSherlock in Eclipse.

But I get 75  errors when I use it in a new project:

```
abs4.1.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:4: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar'.
abs4.1.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:6: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.Solid'.
abs4.1.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar'.
abs4.1.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:10: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid'.
abs4.1.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:12: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse'.
abs4.1.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:15: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView'.
abs4.1.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:17: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
abs4.1.0\library\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:19: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView.Inverse'.
abs4.1.0\library\res\values\abs__styles.xml:89: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:dividerPadding'.
abs4.1.0\library\res\values\abs__styles.xml:88: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:showDividers'.
```

*MainActivity.java*:

```
package com.stackoverflow.users.comfreek.testproject

import android.os.Bundle;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;

public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity {
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
  }
}
```

I already set the activity theme to `@style/Theme.Sherlock`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you've set your API level to 13.

Please see the answer on this similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/8591853/808940

Comment: Thanks! My build target was really set to API level 7 (2.1)! I'll accept your answer in 2 minutes...

Answer (score 0):

Set the deployment target of the project to:

`android >= honeycomb`