# error after updating the support library

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I just updated my libraries when Android 5.0 got lunched today

one of the files that got updated is android-support-v7. after that I kept getting these errors

```
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:75: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:79: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:83: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:25: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:29: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:33: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:37: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:41: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:65: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:69: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:45: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:49: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:53: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:57: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:61: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:178: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:182: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:113: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:115: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:110: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.DropDownItem.Spinner'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:107: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView.DropDown'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:121: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:126: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListPopupWindow'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:138: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:143: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:129: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.PopupMenu'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:132: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.PopupMenu'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:146: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:150: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:154: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:158: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:164: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:168: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:172: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:174: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:93: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Toolbar.Button.Navigation'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:97: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:101: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:62: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:20: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:22: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display4'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:24: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:26: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:28: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:30: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Headline'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:32: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Title'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:34: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Subhead'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:36: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:38: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:40: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:42: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Menu'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:60: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
[2014-10-18 01:05:34 - android-support-v7-appcompat]
```

I tried deleting the library from the SDK manager and download it again

I tried deleting the library and refreshing my project and deleting every line in the build path about android-support-v7-appcompat

I when I set up the bath again I import the library and then add it to my project path

still nothing work, I'm using ADT (Android Developer Tools) not Android Studio

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Modify the `project.properties` file, which has:

```
target=android-19
```

to

```
target=android-21
```

after changes above close project then open and clean

Comment: worked with appcompat but not with mediarouter ... However,Thanks a lot ... you saved me from going to Android Studio

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. Just a side note for others, you only need set this target for the android-support-v7 project. You can keep your own project settings unchanged.

Comment: ^ Incorrect : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23231174/appcompat-v7-error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-t

Answer (score 2):

In order to switch to the API v21 versions of the compat and support libraries, you also have to switch to compileSdkVersion 21 and buildToolsVersion '21.0.1'.

In Android Studio, you set these in build.gradle. In ADT, I don't remember how to set them.

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer I hope someone on Android Studio will use that

Answer (score 0):

Create a new work space after that try to create a new android project with min sdk 2.3 then it will automatically import your appcompact lib after that it will work thats work with me

Answer (score 0):

My solution to a similar error;

1) I installed 21 api with sdk manager.

2) I changed my project's build target to 21. 
   and
   I changed v7-appcompat library build target to 21.

and finally I think support library projects (v7-appcompat or v7-gridlayout) must be in workingset.

Answer (score 0):

If using eclipse make sure you have updated these tools from SDK Manager-

1. Android 5.0(API 21)-SDK Platform
2. Android support repository
3. Android support library
4. Google Play Services
5. Google Repository
6. Latest Build Tools

After updating all of them import v7 project and open the **project.properties** file of the android-support-v7-appcompat and change the target from target=android-19 to **target=android-21** .

Clean the project and you are good to go.