# After migrating to Android API Level 21 my R.java does not get generated

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library, r.java-file, android-appcompat

I have updated (in Eclipse/ADT) to Android 5.0. After getting android-support-v4 and android-support-v7-appcompat (with the help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26436283/error-after-updating-the-support-library/26438055#26438055)) myR.java does not get generated.

When I clean the project, I first get an aapt execution error and then all the error messages for R.??? and  the messages, that R can not be generated.

No, my res directory shows no errors.

Any ideas?

Michael

PS: Newer version of build-tools resolved the problem for me.

Comment: What about the aapt execution error?

Comment: All I see is an `Error executing aapt: Return code -1073741819` and `Android ADT Problem`, which vanishes immediately and the R errors are shown in Problems.

Comment: After upgrading the build tools to 21.0.1 (which came out today) and some restarts and cleans R.java was generated. (Hrmpf, how to mark this thread as resolved?!)

Comment: Check this open issue:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77629

Comment: Have you solve this problem?

Comment: Yes, with an update of the build-tools the problem disappeared.