# How to change an image name in Android Studio

Tags: android, error-handling

I got an app and there is this tiny error about the image name. The name is 'bg.png.png' which was allowed in Eclipse but not in Android Studio. If I fix it, I get 100 errors regarding 'Error retrieving parent for item'.

By the way I am using appcompat7 too. So I don't know how to fix and where this images is called in the code because the code is huge and I am not very good at android.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [appcompat\_v7: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23231174/appcompat-v7-error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-t)

Answer (score 2):

Select the image and press **Shift+F6** (OR Right-click->Refactor->Rename). This will start the **refactoring of selected image name**. change the name to a valid one while highlghted and hit Enter. **It will get renamed in all referenced places**. Will prompt for confirmation so you have a chance to cancel if you feel it is not refactoring correctly. But it works just fine so you need not worry.