# Android_style:error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget'

Tags: android, android-widget, styles

Sorry i have seen lots of this topic questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590521/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name) in Stackoverflow, but none of them has helped me yet.

Here is my manifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

and here is the style `xml` code

```
<style name="Widget.PreferenceFrameLayout">
        <item name="android:borderTop">0dip</item>
        <item name="android:borderBottom">0dip</item>
        <item name="android:borderLeft">0dip</item>
        <item name="android:borderRight">0dip</item>
    </style>
```

The errors are:

```
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget'.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the style is public. So its not possible to customize

Try

```
<style name="@android:style/Widget.PreferenceFrameLayout">
    <item name="android:borderTop">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:borderBottom">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:borderLeft">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:borderRight">0dip</item>
</style>
```

You need to reference the styles in the android framework

And do check this

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml

Comment: Thanks man, now the problem is in the manifest. The error is 
*
error: Error: Resource is not public. (at 'theme' with value '@style/@android:Widget.PreferenceFrameLayout').*

Comment: @Salman its global theme i guess. so its not public i guess. Also you have `@style/@android:Widget.PreferenceFrameLayout'`

Comment: @Salman look at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51452/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-salman)

Answer (score 1):

May be you don't have parent style name `Widget`. If you don't have then add a simple style named `Widget` as in the style resource

```
<style name="Widget"></style>
```

then your `styles.xml` would be look like as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="Widget"></style>

    <style name="Widget.PreferenceFrameLayout">
        <item name="android:borderTop">0dip</item>
        <item name="android:borderBottom">0dip</item>
        <item name="android:borderLeft">0dip</item>
        <item name="android:borderRight">0dip</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```