# Missing styles from android appcompat v7-21.0.0

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I originally was using `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.1'`, and I decided to implement a `DrawerLayout`. Unfortunately, I was informed that the v4 support library's `ActionBarDrawerToggle` is deprecated, and to use the v7 version. It appears that this isn't in the 19.0.1 version of support-v7-appcompat, so I decided to upgrade to `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'`. Now, however, I'm getting the following error in my styles:

```
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.Base.ActionBar.TabBar.Inverse'.
```

(There are a few others).

I've tried a few things, including the following:

- [Error in styles_base.xml file - android app - No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26530415/error-in-styles-base-xml-file-android-app-no-resource-found-that-matches-the)
- [Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590521/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name)

My `build.gradle` has the following configuration:

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 17
 }
```

Comment: Material is for 21+ only. Holo is for 11+ only. ActionBar tabs have been deprecated in v20+. You should always keep your application up to date. It is time for you to a major update.

Comment: We're in the process of a major update, but we're doing one thing at a time - right now, the thing we're working on is the navigation drawer. ;)

Comment: A few other things, `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0` is the latest. You should always target the latest devices `targetSdkVersion` should be set to 22.

Answer (score 0):

The v4 support library's `ActionBarDrawerToggle` was deprecated with the support library v21.

The v7 version was introduced with the `appCompat` library v21.

Also if you are using the `appCompat` library v21 you have to compile with API 21+.

Change your `build.gradle` file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 21       
    }
```

Comment: So, when I do that, I get the error listed in the original question.