# Asking for help: "error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light' "

Tags: android

I'm a freshman in Android. When I create an Android application project in Eclipse, three errors occurred.As follow:
[Details of three errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXZqV.png)

This is the code in styles.xml:

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>
```

To solve this, I have searched a lot of times on the Internet. I did find some solutions on the Internet, but that didn't work.
I would be  really grateful if anybody could help me out~

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590521/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name)

Comment: What exactly have you tried? There are tons of similar questions on SO, have you checked all them?

Answer (score 0):

check your app theme in values-->style folder also in values-v11,values-v14.

check what your activity extend "AppcompactActivity" or "Activity".
if you have to use "Activity" for extend of your activity, then go to style.xml and change parent "theme" like "android:Theme.Light".

Comment: Thanks.
There comes a new error:
\res\menu\main.xml:6: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'com.example.test26'
what should I do...

Comment: eclipse is outdated for android development  try to use android studio